# ChildBrowser plugin for iPhone showing about:blank page

Tags: xcode, jquery-mobile

I am badly stuck with this.I am using phoneagap childbrowser plugin. The window pops up but just shows blank window.The phonegap version I am using is Phonegap 1.2.0 and ios sdk 5.

It is not giving any error but wat i can just see in logs is:

---

View did load

Opening URL: about:blank

New Address is : about:blank

---

I have done following for this:

1. Added ChildBrowser.js to "www" folder.
2. Added ChildBrowserCommand.h, ChildBrowserCommand.m, ChildBrowserViewController.h, ChildBrowserViewController.m files in "Plugin" folder.
3. Added ChildBrowser.bundle and ChildBrowserViewController.xib in "Resources" folder
4. Added following plugins in phonegap.plist file :

   Key: ChildBrowserCommand Value: ChildBrowserCommand

   Key: ChildBrowser Value: ChildBrowser.js.

I replaced the follwing in appdelegate.m file as my childbrowser window was not getting opened:

---

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView     

shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:    

(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
       if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"])

       {

       //This code will open any url that is not in the PhoneGap whitelist in Child Browser


        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request  
              navigationType:navigationType ];
    }
```

---

WITH

---

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView

shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request

navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme]
                                                   isEqualToString:@"https"])

{
      return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request
                navigationType:navigationType ];

    }

        if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"gap"] || [url isFileURL]) {

        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request

                navigationType:navigationType ];

    }

    else {

        ChildBrowserViewController* childBrowser =

        [ [ ChildBrowserViewController alloc ] initWithScale:FALSE ];

        [super.viewController presentModalViewController:childBrowser

                                                animated:YES ];
        [childBrowser loadURL:[url description]];

        [childBrowser release];
        return NO;

    }

}
```

---

After this, childbrowser pops up but with blank screen.

Prompt help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Prabhjot